# How to take the count object inside object using mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregate, aggregation

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : "123",
    "gallary" : {
        "profilepic" : [
            "200"
        ]
    }
},
```

My requirement is suppose `gallary.profilepic` is object **{}**

> Expected output:

```
count : 3
```

Note: _id `456` profilepic an object so we have to take count (2) & `789` profilepic is an object so we have to take count (1) so output should come 2 + 1 = 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this aggregation

- `$type` to identify the type of object and to filter
- `$objectToArray` to convert the object to array to get the size

pipeline

```
 db.t51.aggregate([
    {$addFields : {type : {$type : "$gallary.profilepic"}}}, 
    {$match : {type : "object"}}, 
    {$group : {_id : null, count : {$sum : {$size : {$objectToArray : "$gallary.profilepic"}}}}}
 ])
```

output

```
{ "_id" : null, "count" : 3 }
```

In mongo 3.6, you can remove `$addFields` and `$match` stages with `$expr` in `$match` stage

Comment: Thanks dude, i got my answer

Comment: i need one help from this query, can you please update ?

Comment: are you there ?

Comment: I had edited my question, please check **Updated Requirement** section

Comment: You shouldn't edit the answered question, please create one and share the link

Comment: you can't update with aggregation, you've to `find` document, iterate and batch `update`